# ¿Por qué no al abrir un enlace, este se abra en otra pestaña?

Tags: discusión, interfaz-de-usuario

He estado viendo que, ya sea que coloquen un enlace en una pregunta, un comentario o directamente que la misma pagina lo otorgue, sí a este se le da <kbd>click</kbd> se abre en la misma pagina, y esto puede dificultar un poco la navegabilidad, según mi opinión, ya qué, sí estoy leyendo una pregunta y le doy al enlace, pues se abre al instante y me pierdo en la pregunta, o estoy viendo alguna pregunta en StackOverflow en Español y quiero rectificar algo en el meta, entonces, se me pierde la pregunta, o cosas así, no sé si me hago entender y quiero ver que puntos de vista tienen.

Comment: ¿Qué navegadore estás usando? ¿ya revisaste cómo está configurado en lo que clic en enlaces se refiere?

Comment: Chrome, y sí, pero sí es como algo interno dentro de la plataforma está bien, pero ya en el momento de que el enlace sea para llevarlo a algo externo o que sea que lo pongan en un comentario o pregunta, o también el mismo hecho de cambiar de comunidad o ver el centro de ayuda, cosas así, yo pienso que es como más cómodo que directamente se abra como una pestaña aparte y que no se redireccione en la pagina

Comment: En teoría, los enlaces no se deberían abrir en una nueva pestaña/ventana por motivos de usabilidad y accesibilidad. El comportamiento por defecto de un enlace es abrirse en la misma ventana y siempre se puede abrir en una nueva ventana pulsando en el botón secundario o terciario del ratón (o con Ctrl+click). Pero si ese comportamiento se cambia para que el enlace se abra en una nueva pestaña, no hay manera de abrirlo en la misma.

Comment: Ya, pero pues tomando en cuenta al menos los enlaces externos, ya sea una demo en otra pagina, una pagina de referencia, etc. haría que en el momento que lo abras se pierda lo que estabas leyendo, ya sea en la respuesta, en la pregunta o en la respuesta, entonces, hace más tedioso abrir el stack otra vez, y buscar la preguntar para responder o comentar, y sí, yo utilizo el click de en medio, pero pues, hay gente que no, por eso también lo reitero

Comment: En principio no deberías perder tu esbozo de pregunta o respuesta. Aunque cambies de página se guarda y se vuelves atrás te lo encontrarás.

Answer (score 1):

Respuesta corta

En Chrome, para abrir el enlace en una nueva pestaña / ventana, usa

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + clic (nueva pestaña en la misma ventana)
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + clic (nueva ventana)

Rollo

Sin citar referencias sobre usabilidad de interfaz de usuario estaríamos hablando en el ámbito de gustos personales, por otro lado, si lo que deseas saber son los criterios de los diseñadores del sistema y si sabes inglés, es muy probable que esto ya se haya discutido en https://meta.stackexchange.com

En atención a los que no saben inglés, quizás algún miembro de la comunidad, incluido  yo mismo en otro momento, podría hacer un resumen para que estén informados.

Por otro lado, si encuentras una falta de consistencia en cómo funcionan los enlaces, eso sería un bug.

Comment: Añadir que en cualquier navegador, pulsar un enlace con el botón central (rueda), abrirá dicho enlace también en una nueva pestaña.